# Why Im getting error 440 : Method 'Create ' of object 'Pivotcaches' failed in the below code?

Tags: excel, vba

getting error at line no 2:

```
wsNewSheet5.Activate
Set myCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(database, Range("a2").CurrentRegion)
wsNewSheet6.Activate
Set myPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(myCache1, Range("A4"), "myPivot1")

    With myPivot
        .PivotFields("DR / CR").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("AMOUNT").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Concatinate No").Orientation = xlRowField
    End With
```

I did the same steps for my previous project and it is working fine.
I tried by using range like A1:C100 but still it is not working

Comment: What is `database`? Did you mean `xlDatabase`